# Karma not running jasmine specs

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am setting up a new project and trying to get karma working.  When I run karma, it keeps reporting:

> Executed 0 of 0 ERROR.

At this point my project consists of just a few js files and one `test.js` file.  Here is my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      {pattern: '../app/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: '**/*.js', included: false}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    plugins: [
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',

    ]
  });
};
```

I can see that it is loading my test file by turning on log debugging and I see this:

```
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
  ...
  c:/dev/forms/tests/forms/form-page-controller-tests.js
  ...
```

The contents of form-page-controller-tests.js is:

```
describe("A suite", function() {
    it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

And yet it still says Executed 0 of 0.  If I have the jasmine framework specified and the jasmine plugin specified, why does it not see and execute this test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you declare `{pattern: '**/*.js', included: false}` as a file pattern. That tells karma not to load any JS file, including your test file.
Try changing `included` to `true`.

Comment: D'oh!  How did I not see that.  Thank you.